# cannot remove components and repaint

Tags: java, swing, components, repaint

I've got this problem. I wanna to remove all existing components from a JPanel and add another new after button click. Now, if I click on a button, it will add the same button at a top left corner but nothing is clickable anymore.

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

private Image backgroundImage;
private Image startScreen;
private boolean gameStarted = false;
private SingleplayerButton button1;
private MultiplayerButton button2;

public MainPanel() {
    String imgUrl = "graphics/";
    try {
        startScreen = ImageIO.read(new File(imgUrl+"start.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
    backgroundImage = startScreen;
    this.setLayout(null);
    button1 = new SingleplayerButton(this);
    button1.addActionListener(this);
    this.add(button1);

    button2 = new MultiplayerButton(this);
    button2.addActionListener(this);
    this.add(button2);
}


@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if(gameStarted == false) {
        g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
    } else {
        this.removeAll();
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.revalidate();
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == button1) {
        gameStarted = true;
        this.repaint();
        // something more
    } else if(e.getSource() == button2) {
        gameStarted = true;
        this.repaint();
        // something more
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you post an actual SSCCE? This code wont even compile.

Comment: Maybe the content is not disappearing because you don't call super.paintComponent(g); on the top of paintComponent method. And I agree with the answer below if you don't need graphics don't remove, revalidate and repaint in the paintComponent method. Do this in the listener

Comment: @FelipeO.Thomé, the paintComponent() method is not responsible for painting the children of the panel. The paint() method paints the children. See [A Closer Look at the Painting Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) for more information.

Comment: @camickr We don't need to call super paintComponent to erase whatever is drawn on the panel?

Comment: the problem was with background ... it would not disappear :-/ So I decided to create another background image for next screen and swaping the bg images ... now it's OK.
Why setBackground(Color.WHITE); did not function? :-/

Comment: `the problem was with background ... it would not disappear` as @FelipeO.Thomé, has suggested you need to invoke super.paintComponent().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic code when you add/remove a component from a visible GUI is:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

The above code should be done in the ActionListener, NOT in the paintComponent() method. Painting methods are for painting only.